# Clipping Raster by value depending extent of another Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I have two Raster datasets in ArcGIS. Raster1 is a Digital Elevation Model, has z-values. Raster2 has the same extent, but contains a different parameter, h-values.

Now, what i want to do is cut/clip/extract the Raster2 to the extent of the DEM (Raster1) with z-values >= 5.67m or <=-5.67m only.

Up to now i used the following processing steps:
[image: several processing steps leading to the desired results in ModelBuilder ArcGIS]
This workflow works (not yet automatically). However, i think it is not very effective. Especially when i want to repeat this step with several other masks (beside DEM). Do you know if there is a better way to achieve the same results?

Comment: Yes, this is working and what i was looking for. Actually, i used CON before, but in a different way. However, i did not set the environment settings. Why is that important? Can you formulate an answer, that i can mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model can be reduced to a single tool, you can complete the logic with a [CON](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) tool whilst setting some of the environmental settings.

Typically you would want to set the *snap raster* environment which ensures that the two rasters are aligned as they may have different extents. This is a typical problem when the rasters are derived from vector datasets.

Setting the *extent* limits where it is processing data, so in your example the dataset you want to clip (raster 2) could be many times larger than the DEM. Setting the extent will limit the area of processing and can significantly improve performance.